# How can I parse this HTML table using XPATHs?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, mechanicalsoup

I'm trying to get the contents of an HTML table using XPaths, I'm using Mechanicalsoup to grab the form and submit it (The data is behind a submission form) once I hit the second form I grab the URL and pass it for parsing but I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'`

```
import mechanicalsoup
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree


#This Will Use Mechanical Soup to grab the Form, Subit it and find the Data Table
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
winnet = "http://winnet.wartburg.edu/coursefinder/"
browser.open(winnet)
Searchform = browser.select_form()
Searchform.choose_submit('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$Button_FindNow')
response1 = browser.submit_selected() #This Progresses to Second Form
dataURL = 'https://winnet.wartburg.edu/coursefinder/Results.aspx' #Get URL of Second Form w/ Data


pageContent=requests.get(dataURL)
tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)
dataTable = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]')
print(dataTable)
for row in dataTable.xpath(".//tr")[1:]:
    print([cell.text_content() for cell in row.xpath(".//td")])

#XPath to Table
#//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]
```

I'd post the HTML I'm trying to parse but it is incredibly long and from what I've seen of some other sites I've worked with it is incredibly sloppily written

Comment: Can you post your `dataURL`?

Comment: I set the dataURL in my code equal to the URL I'm grabbing. Just so you are aware the form is blank unless the first form performs a search. My mechnicalsoup portion of the code should be submitting that form to get a populated results page.

Comment: Try `print(type(dataTable))` which I am guessing will show you why you're getting the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe you are after something like this. If that's not it, you can probably modify it to get you where you want to be.

```
import pandas as pd
rows = [] #initialize a collection of rows
for row in dataTable[0].xpath(".//tr")[1:]: #add new rows to the collection
    rows.append([cell.text_content().strip() for cell in row.xpath(".//td")])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows) #load the collection to a dataframe
df
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

> View Details AC 121 01 Principles of Accounting I Pilcher, A M W F
>   10:45AM-11:50AM 45/40/0 WBC 116 2019-20 WI
>   1.00
>
> View Details AC 122 01 Principles of Accounting II Pilcher, A MWF
>   12:00PM-1:05PM 45/42/0 WBC 116 2019-20 WI
>   1.00

etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. did you make by chance any modifications to the connection to results page? I'm having an issue I was afraid of having in which the Results Page is blank.

Comment: @RobertFarmer - No, didn't touch that, I'm afraid.